# How do I re-import menus and blocks?

Tags: 7, blocks, importing-exporting

I've got a local install that has turned bad. I want to quickly re-import block settings, block content, and menus.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export blocks with the [Features Extra](https://drupal.org/project/features_extra) module, or better yet, use the [Boxes](https://drupal.org/project/boxes) module, which is designed to be exportable.

Using MySQL dumps is an advanced trick that gets harder with each version of Drupal as the API becomes more complex. It's not recommended and definitely not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 1):

If your importing to a brand new install then a selective dump of the menu and block tables should be ok, this way it won't overwrite any existing custom menus.

If the export site isn't too messed up then you can always look at exporting the menus and blocks as a [feature](http://drupal.org/project/features) and then import it into the new site.