# Export blocks to production site

Tags: 6, theming, blocks, staging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Quickest way to reimport menus and blocks (D7)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6489/quickest-way-to-reimport-menus-and-blocks-d7)

**I need a way to easily transfer the block configuration from my staging site over to the live site.**

I've been working on implementing a new theme for my client and showing them my progress using a staging site, which is basically a clone of the live site. The staging site's blocks configuration is completely different from the live site.

I've heard about the [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module, but unless i'm mistaken, it doesn't work with Blocks. Maybe I need to use [Chaos Tools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools)?

I'm just trying to avoid having to manually place each block in its correct position when it's time to go live, which would be very time consuming. Using exportable blocks sounds like a good idea, but I am unsure if it is a safe procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Yo will need to use the [Features Extra](http://drupal.org/project/features_extra) module. It currently supports: vocabularies; nodequeues (definitions); block settings; **custom blocks** (boxes).